# Swift Classes fundamental D.R.Y principle

Tags: ios, swift, class

Having a class called Nike and creating an instance of the class is what I think I should do to avoid code duplication. Is that the smartest approach?

```
enum Condition {
    case poor
    case fair
    case excellent
}

class Shoe {

var color: Condition
var laces: Condition

init(color: Condition, laces: Condition) {
    self.color = color
    self.laces = laces
}

}

class Nikeone: Shoe {

var texture: Condition
var sole: Condition

 init(color: Condition, laces: Condition, texture: Condition, sole: Condition) {
  self.texture = texture
  self.sole = sole
super.init(color: color, laces: laces)
 }
}




class NikeTwo: Shoe {

var texture: Condition
var sole: Condition

init(color: Condition, laces: Condition, texture: Condition, sole: Condition) {
    self.texture = texture
    self.sole = sole
    super.init(color: color, laces: laces)
}

 }

class NikeThree: Shoe {

var texture: Condition
var sole: Condition

init(color: Condition, laces: Condition, texture: Condition, sole: Condition) {
    self.texture = texture
    self.sole = sole
    super.init(color: color, laces: laces)
}
}
```

Having a class called Nike and creating an instance of the class is what I think I should do to avoid code duplication. Is that the smartest approach?

Comment: Yes. Create a Nike class, and get rid of Nikeone, NikeTwo, and NikeThree. You would then perhaps create instances of nikeOne, nikeTwo and NikeThree somewhere in your program. Your Nike class would look exactly like the three you have here (it would replace all three).

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is to create a base class called `Shoe`, as you suggested.

```
enum Condition {
    case poor
    case fair
    case excellent
}

class Shoe {
    var color: Condition
    var laces: Condition

    init(color: Condition, laces: Condition) {
        self.color = color
        self.laces = laces
    }
}
```

You would then create a subclass called `NikeShoe`:

```
class NikeShoe: Shoe {
    var texture: Condition
    var sole: Condition

    init(color: Condition, laces: Condition, texture: Condition, sole: Condition) {
        self.texture = texture
        self.sole = sole
        super.init(color: color, laces: laces)
    }
}
```

You would then create the shoes you'd like:

```
let shoeA = NikeShoe(…)
let shoeB = NikeShoe(…)
```